# Thread runOnUiThread pausing/resume after notify() not continue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Iam making app for listening .mp3 words in greek language and displaying them after 2000ms but when i pause thread and then notify() back thread never runs again... TextView is changing every 2000ms but when i pause it and notify() run() block is not executing anything anymore and app crashes.. What iam doing wrong ?

```
class MyinnerThread implements Runnable  {
    String name;
    Thread tr;
    boolean suspendFlag;
    int i = 0;

    MyinnerThread(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        tr = new Thread(this, name);
        suspendFlag = false;
        tr.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            while(!suspendFlag){

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(i == 0){tv1.setText("trhead1");}
                    if(i == 1){tv2.setText("trhead2");}
                    if(i == 2){tv3.setText("trhead3");}
                    if(i == 3){tv4.setText("trhead4");}
                    if(i == 4){tv5.setText("trhead5");}
                    if(i == 5){tv6.setText("trhead6");}
                    if(i == 6){tv7.setText("trhead7");}
                    if(i == 7){tv8.setText("trhead8");}

                    synchronized(signal) {
                        while(suspendFlag) {
                            try {
                                signal.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            i++;

           }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
    }
    void mysuspend() {
        suspendFlag = true;
    }

     void myresume() {

        synchronized(signal) {
            suspendFlag = false;
            signal.notify();
        }

}
```

}

EDIT: Final code here and working !

```
run() {

    try {
        while(true){

         synchronized(signal) {
               while(suspendFlag) {
                     try {
                         signal.wait();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              //....
                }
            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        i++;
       }
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: signal.wait() is called from within the UI thread (I assume, runOnUIThread will execute the given Runnable on the UI thread). This will block/freeze the UI.

Comment: so u should put singal.wait() up to run() i mean out of runOnUIThread ? Look to update

Comment: Yes. And rethink the main loop "while (!suspendFlag)"! This will abort the entire task instead of just suspending it.

Comment: i put while(true) and it seems to working

Comment: finally, make suspendFlag volatile to avoid visibility issues.

Comment: done :) thank you very much :) i would like to give you a reputation :) nice day for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `signal.wait()` is called from within the UI thread (I assume, `runOnUIThread` will execute the given `Runnable` on the UI thread). This will block/freeze the UI. Take it out of the `run()` method and put into the threads 'main loop'.
2. Rethink the main loop `while (!suspendFlag)`! This will abort the entire task instead of just suspending it.
3. Finally, make `suspendFlag` `volatile` to avoid visibility issues.